# PHP - Force eval() to run in global scope?

Tags: php, scope, eval

This is not a duplicate, as my requirements are that the eval() statement MUST be in the function. Also, I do not require that the function “set_myvar” return anything at all.

Say I have this code (ignore how silly it is; it's just hypothetical):

```
$myvar = null;
function set_myvar(){
eval("$myvar = 'Hello world';");
}
set_myvar();
echo $myvar;
```

Can I force eval() to be called in the global scope, so that the program echoes "Hello world"?

Comment: Your question and your desired results seem to be different. Calling `eval()` in the global scope implies that you want all variables available in the global scope to be available to your `eval()`. Your desired result is to have `$myvar` available in the global scope after you call `eval()` from `set_myvar()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mandatory disclaimer: in my self-inflated opinion, eval() is a code smell. If you need it
for something other than a quick&dirty hack, *somehow, somewhere, you're doing something wrong*.

That said... as I see it, you need two runs of `eval()`.

Your current code is, say:

```
$program = '...';
eval($program);
```

And program will set some variables, have some side effects, and maybe be slow as well.

We don't want to run *it* twice; we just need to discover how it affects the scope, to replicate it at leisure.

What you can do is add to $program a small piece which will use `get_defined_vars()` or `var_export()` to provide a representation of the environment that is ordered and machine parsable, and return that:

```
$program .= "return get_defined_vars();"
```

Once you have it, you can have an assignment that has no more side effects than setting the variables you need. All you need to do now is execute it in the global scope.

But with this method you also have a list of the names of the variables in that environment:

```
$names = array_keys($returnedVars);
```

You can then extract those names, and add a "global" at the start:

```
$program2
```

is now  "global $var1, $var2, $var3...\n extract($returnedVars);" with environment coming from the return value of the first eval().

And by eval()'ing *that* second program, the variables should be injected into the global scope
with a minimum of fuss.

Comment: Your method of using "get_defined_vars()" to expand out a list of global variables before running eval() worked perfectly. Thanks!